# getPath() does not return subfolder for S3 asset source

Tags: assets, s3

I'm reading through the Craft docs in relation to the AssetFileModel.

Looking at the `getPath()` method, this reads in theory that it should return the full path to the asset relative to the root, with any sub directories etc.

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/models/AssetFileModel.html#getPath-detail

Yet this doesn't to appear to be the case, I seem to be getting `/filename.ext`

If however I was to use `folderPath()` this then provides the subfolder name configured in the relevant S3 asset source.

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master-v2/src/models/AssetFileModel.php#L384

Is this correct? Is `getPath()` meant to behave this way with S3 asset sources?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working as expected for me.  I've got an Asset Source setup with an S3 bucket.

At the root of the bucket, there is a `test1` folder and in it is a `test2` folder... i.e. `root/test1/test2/`.  From there, I put a `test.jpg` file inside of `test2`.

When I do this from a template (where ID is the Asset ID for `test.jpg`:

```
{% set image = craft.assets.id(13).first() %}

{{ image.getPath() }}
```

I get the expected:

```
test1/test2/test.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks Brad. Its interesting, because I'm using a plugin that uses getPath and this doesn't appear to be the case. For reference its this plugin relating to the service file here: https://github.com/sjelfull/Craft-CloudFrontInvalidation/blob/master/cloudfrontinvalidation/services/CloudfrontInvalidationService.php. I did report to the author, but I'm still not sure if I'm missing something.